# Can not close EntityManager after doing a rollback

Tags: hibernate, jboss, entitymanager, jta

Following is my environment specifications:

Server: JBOSS6.1 final

Persistence layer: JPA with Hibernate as persistence provider (Hibernate version 3.6.6.Final)

Application architecture is like: Controller -> Session Beans -> Businell Logic Layer -> Builder (Hibernate layer) - DB (MYSQL)

We are using "RESOURCE_LOCAL" transaction which is configured in the persistence.xml as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <non-jta-data-source>java:/TestDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

And we use the transactions as shown below:

```
try {
  txUtil.beginTransaction();
  <-- some entity update etc here -->
  if(some validation fail here){
      txUtil.rollbackTransaction();
  } else {
      txUtil.commitTransaction();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      txUtil.rollbackTransaction();
  } finally {
      try {
          txUtil.closeEntityManager();
      } catch (BAException e) {
          log.warn("Problem occurred while closing the EntityManager: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
      }
  }
```

Where the code for various methods used above is something like (below is not exact impl but a crude representation of what we have):

```
beginTransaction(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    if(em.isOpen())
    {
            transaction = em.getTransaction();
            if(!transaction.isActive())
            {   
                transaction.begin();
            }
    }
}


commitTransaction(){
    if(em.isOpen())
    {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        if(transaction.isActive())
        {   
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}

rollbackTransaction(){
    if(em.isOpen())
    {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        if(transaction.isActive())
        {   
            log.debug("EntityManager for thread (" + 
                Thread.currentThread().hashCode() +
                ") has active transaction (" + 
                transaction.hashCode() + "): rollback");
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
}

closeEntityManager() {
    if(em.isOpen()) {
        EntityTransaction tx=em.getTransaction();
        if(tx==null) {
           log.debug("No transaction associated with EntityManager");
        } else {
            if(tx.isActive()) {
               log.debug("EntityManager has active transaction, rolling out");
               tx.rollback();
            } else {
               log.debug("EntityManager transaction was not active");
            }
        }
     } try {
        em.close();
     }
}
```

The problem is that anytime we do a rollback and then if we try to close the entity manager, it throws a rollback exception. The stacktrace for the same is as follows:

```
04:46:16,378 ERROR [STDERR] org.hibernate.TransactionException: could not register synchronization
04:46:16,384 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransaction.registerSynchronization(JTATransaction.java:316)
04:46:16,385 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:125)
04:46:16,386 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.test.builder.util.EntityManagerUtil.rollbackAndCloseEntityManager(EntityManagerUtil.java:201)
04:46:16,387 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.test.builder.util.TransactionUtilImpl.closeEntityManager(TransactionUtilImpl.java:40)
04:46:16,391 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
04:46:16,392 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
04:46:16,393 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
04:46:16,394 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
04:46:16,395 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
04:46:16,396 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
04:46:16,397 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
04:46:16,398 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
04:46:16,399 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
04:46:16,401 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor950.invoke(Unknown Source)
04:46:16,402 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
04:46:16,403 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
04:46:16,404 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
04:46:16,405 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,406 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
04:46:16,407 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_446939511.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_446939511.java)
04:46:16,408 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,408 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
04:46:16,409 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_446939511.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_446939511.java)
04:46:16,410 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,411 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128)
04:46:16,412 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,414 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
04:46:16,415 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,416 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
04:46:16,417 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,418 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
04:46:16,419 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,420 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
04:46:16,421 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,422 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
04:46:16,423 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,424 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95)
04:46:16,425 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:247)
04:46:16,426 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
04:46:16,427 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
04:46:16,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
04:46:16,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
04:46:16,432 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
04:46:16,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,436 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
04:46:16,436 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
04:46:16,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
04:46:16,440 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,441 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
04:46:16,442 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,443 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
04:46:16,444 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,446 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
04:46:16,447 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,448 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:392)
04:46:16,449 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:88)
04:46:16,450 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:75)
04:46:16,451 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,452 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
04:46:16,453 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
04:46:16,454 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
04:46:16,455 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy215.invoke(Unknown Source)
04:46:16,456 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
04:46:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy224.addMyEntity(Unknown Source)
04:46:16,458 ERROR [STDERR]     at test.mycomp.services.MyServicesImpl.addMyEntity(MyServicesImpl.java:134)
04:46:16,459 ERROR [STDERR]     at tv.mycomp.controllers.MyController.addMyEntity(MyController.java:106)
04:46:16,460 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
04:46:16,461 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
04:46:16,462 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
04:46:16,463 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
04:46:16,464 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:472)
04:46:16,465 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:409)
04:46:16,466 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
04:46:16,468 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
04:46:16,469 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
04:46:16,470 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
04:46:16,471 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
04:46:16,472 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
04:46:16,473 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
04:46:16,474 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
04:46:16,475 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
04:46:16,476 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
04:46:16,478 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274)
04:46:16,479 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
04:46:16,480 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
04:46:16,481 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
04:46:16,482 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
04:46:16,484 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
04:46:16,485 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
04:46:16,486 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
04:46:16,487 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
04:46:16,488 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
04:46:16,489 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
04:46:16,490 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
04:46:16,491 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
04:46:16,492 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
04:46:16,493 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
04:46:16,494 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
04:46:16,495 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
04:46:16,496 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
04:46:16,498 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
04:46:16,501 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA-16083 Can't register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state
04:46:16,502 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronizationImple(TransactionImple.java:363)
04:46:16,503 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronization(TransactionImple.java:344)
04:46:16,504 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransaction.registerSynchronization(JTATransaction.java:313)
04:46:16,505 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 108 more
```

And following are the transaction related attributes from the persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />

<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />

<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
```

Everywhere I have seen and read about closing the entity manager after rolling back a transaction. But why am I getting the above exception? Is it expected or am I missing something here?

Thanks a lot in advance, please let me know if you need any further information regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a bug.  However, we no longer support Hibernate 3.6.  Can you reproduce that in 4.1?  The stack trace is different from 4.1...

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, I will try that out with Hibernate 4.1 and let you know about my findings.